# Reduce row spacing in verbatim environment?

Tags: fonts, line-spacing

In this example I would like a continuous display for box characters which is not yet the case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{dejavu}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
    ┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

With the current code I get this:

[image]

In my text editor it's fine:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the row space is the minimum vertical spaces inserted between `\vbox`es. It is controlled by `\lineskip` and has initial value `1pt`. In the following example I set `\lineskip` to zero inside every `verbatim` environment and it seems  to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{dejavu}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
    ┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As [muzimuzhi Z says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557536/4427), the problem is `\lineskip`, whose default value is 1pt. Since the lines would touch each other, TeX inserts `\lineskip` glue.

However, there are other problems with your code: blank spaces are preserved at the beginning of lines, so your `verbatim` environment is indented.

In my opinion, one should *never* indent the contents of a `verbatim` environment. If an indent is wanted, it's better to use `fancyvrb` features; among them there is the possibility of gobbling initial spaces, but I don't recommend it.

You can also say `\fvsetup{formatcom=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}}` in the preamble, if you want this setting to hold in every `Verbatim` environment (note the uppercase initial).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}]
┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
│0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}]
    ┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt},gobble=4]
    ┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt},gobble=4,xleftmargin=\parindent]
    ┞─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┦
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for catching the indentation.